# How to tag image with short commit SHA in CodeBuild

Tags: git, sh, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to get the short git SHA of a commit from a CodeBuild build when it is triggered from a new commit in the main branch.

I know that `CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION` contains the full commit SHA. I want to shrink this value to tag the output image before pushing it to ECR.

I tried in the `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      ...
      - COMMIT_ID=${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION:0:8}
      ...
  build:
    commands:
      ...
      - echo Tagging image with commit id $COMMIT_ID
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:latest $REPOSITORY_URI/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_ID
      ...
  post_build:
    commands:
      ...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_ID
```

But I get:

```
[Container] 2022/07/07 11:30:05 Running command COMMIT_ID=${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION:0:8}
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: Bad substitution
```

Why may this be?

Comment: That's not an answer to your question, but be careful hardcoding the length to 8, sometimes that's not long enough to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Bad substitution` error likely comes from that the command is interpreted in a shell that does not understand the bash substitution syntax (for example `sh`)

You could use `cut` instead to extract the substring in a fully POSIX compliant way:

```bash
COMMIT_ID=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -b -8)
```

However if you are looking for the short commit hash it is safer to get that using git, then you will be sure you get just the right length (whether it is less equal to or more than 8) to be unique:

```bash
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

Comment: And in general, rather than a commit hash (abbreviated or not), I'd prefer the `git describe` result, but `git rev-parse --short HEAD` is the way to go when using a shortened hash.

Comment: `git describe` certainly has its uses, but for most CI/CD scenarios I actually prefer to use the hash (or other information that can be derived from the commit) to create an ID or version. Using only commit specific information, like hash, date of commit etc. the ID becomes reproduceable regardless of when in time you generate it or from which branch/tag you are doing it. On the other hand, the output of `git describe` may change if tags are added.

Comment: That's true, but note that unless you *delete* some tag, the output from `git describe` can still pin down a specific revision, even if a new `git describe` produces a different string. Well, modulo any bugs in `git describe`: someone found a doozy recently! Seriously-wrong output...